# DependencyManagement with transitive multi-module dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a parent module A with a child B. 
B has a dependency on a lib C and transitively on D.version1 (so I can't change the version directly).

Because D.version1 has a CVE vulnerability, I want to change D to version2, which is retrocompatible with previous versions.

[First diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Z6r.png)

Now, B is a dependency of a module E

[Second diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ymj.png)

- Why the version of D in module E has rollbacked to version1?

  - If this is the real behavior, how could I override the D version **from** A/B ?

Comment: If you like to defined in that way you have to define the version of the artifact directly in your own project which has always priority over the ones which are coming through the dependency tree (nearest wins strategy).

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to know if there is another way to do it properly

Comment: A dependencymanagement entry will win against all transitive definitions of the dependency version.

Comment: So if you set dependencymanagement of D to version 2, and you have neither direct dependencies on D nor other dependencymanagement entries for D, D will have version 2. IMHO,  this is a cleaner strategy than adding unnecessary direct dependencies.